# Get a function argument from a parent call

Tags: r

I'd like to write a wrapper function that adds some extra functionality to the function it modifies. How do I get the `func` argument properly from the parent function?

```
foo <- function(func) {
  function(x) {
    # some extra features
    func(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: What you show works as is.  As func is not defined in the inner function it looks into the environment where the inner function was defined and that is the outer function where it finds it.  For example try `foo(exp)(0)`

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Is it possible then to wrap a function around itself like `bar <- foo(bar)`?

Comment: Yes, certainly although you might want to call it bar2 or something else so that you don't overwrite the input as that will make debugging easier.  `exp2 <- foo(exp); exp2(0)`

Comment: The problem is, I'm getting into an infinite recursion when I'm trying to implement overwriting.

Comment: That is due to lazy evaluation. Add this line as the first line of the body of foo:  `force(func)` to force the argument to be evaluated.